# Question about tidyverse and ggplot2 plots

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, ggplot2, plot

I am using survey data and i would like to plot activity categories through time of the day.

My AggregatedActivity matrix consists of variables that define activities (such as sleepAct, eatinAct, etc..).

```
Below dput(head(AggregatedActivities, 20))

structure(c(0, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 17, 15, 
14, 20, 25, 21, 157, 155, 155, 153, 150, 150, 147, 146, 145, 
146, 146, 142, 134, 133, 124, 113, 113, 104, 85, 76, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 9, 6, 6, 13, 13, 5, 5, 5, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 4, 7, 5, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 4, 6, 6, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 
3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 5), .Dim = c(20L, 52L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", "04:50", "05:00", 
    "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", "06:00", "06:10", 
    "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", "07:10"), c("personalcareAct", 
    "sleepAct", "eatingAct", "workingAct", "studyAct", "tidyAct", 
    "foodprepAct", "dishesAct", "foodmanagementAct", "householdtidyAct", 
    "hobbyAct", "ironingAct", "laundryAct", "hobby2Act", "gardeningAct", 
    "petsAct", "diyAct", "hobby1Act", "vehiclemaintenanceAct", 
    "shoppingAct", "servicesAct", "tidyNotUsingInternetAct", 
    "InternetAct", "childcareAct", "adultcareAct", "organisationalworkAct", 
    "helpothersAct", "socialAct", "culturalAct", "libraryAct", 
    "sportseventsAct", "leisureAct", "sportsAct", "computerAct", 
    "unspecifiedartsAct", "correspondanceAct", "unspecifedhobbyAct", 
    "computingAct", "OnlinecommunicationAct", "computingunspecifiedAct", 
    "skypeorvideocallAct", "OtherunspecifiedcomputingAct", "gamesAct", 
    "computergamesAct", "gamblingAct", "unspecifedmassmediaAct", 
    "readingAct", "TVAct", "RadioAct", "travelAct", "waitingAct", 
    "unknownAct")))
```

what I am to do is to plot the columns (that describe activities) of the matrix against time (4am till 4am).

Using the above code I generated the following plot:

```
AggregatedActivities<-as.matrix(cbind(personalcareAct, sleepAct, eatingAct, workingAct,
                                      studyAct, tidyAct, foodprepAct, dishesAct, foodmanagementAct,
                                      householdtidyAct, hobbyAct, ironingAct, laundryAct, hobby2Act,
                                      gardeningAct, petsAct, diyAct, hobby1Act, vehiclemaintenanceAct,
                                      shoppingAct, servicesAct, tidyNotUsingInternetAct,
                                      InternetAct, childcareAct, adultcareAct, organisationalworkAct,
                                      helpothersAct, socialAct, culturalAct, libraryAct,
                                      sportseventsAct, leisureAct, sportsAct, computerAct, 
                                      unspecifiedartsAct, correspondanceAct, unspecifedhobbyAct,
                                      computingAct, OnlinecommunicationAct, computingunspecifiedAct,
                                      skypeorvideocallAct, OtherunspecifiedcomputingAct, gamesAct,
                                      computergamesAct, gamblingAct, unspecifedmassmediaAct,
                                      readingAct, TVAct, RadioAct, travelAct, waitingAct, unknownAct))


rownames(AggregatedActivities) <-  c("04:00", "04:10","04:20", "04:30", "04:40", "04:50", "05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50",
                         "06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", 
                         "07:00", "07:10", "07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50",
                         "08:00", "08:10", "08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50",
                         "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", "09:30", "09:40", "09:50", 
                         "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", "10:40", "10:50", 
                         "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", "11:50", 
                         "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", 
                         "13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50",
                         "14:00", "14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", 
                         "15:00", "15:10", "15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", 
                         "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", "16:30", "16:40", "16:50", 
                         "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", "17:40", "17:50", 
                         "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", "18:50",
                         "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", 
                         "20:00", "20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", 
                         "21:00", "21:10", "21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", 
                         "22:00", "22:10", "22:20", "22:30", "22:40", "22:50",  
                         "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", "23:30", "23:40", "23:50",
                         "00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", "00:40", "00:50", 
                         "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", "01:50",
                         "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", 
                         "03:00", "03:10", "03:20", "03:30" ,"03:40", "03:50")




colnames(AggregatedActivities) <-  c("personalcareAct", "sleepAct", "eatingAct", "workingAct",
                                     "studyAct", "tidyAct", "foodprepAct", "dishesAct", "foodmanagementAct",
                                     "householdtidyAct", "hobbyAct", "ironingAct", "laundryAct", "hobby2Act",
                                     "gardeningAct", "petsAct", "diyAct", "hobby1Act", "vehiclemaintenanceAct",
                                     "shoppingAct", "servicesAct", "tidyNotUsingInternetAct",
                                     "InternetAct", "childcareAct", "adultcareAct", "organisationalworkAct",
                                     "helpothersAct", "socialAct", "culturalAct", "libraryAct",
                                     "sportseventsAct", "leisureAct", "sportsAct", "computerAct", 
                                     "unspecifiedartsAct", "correspondanceAct", "unspecifedhobbyAct",
                                     "computingAct", "OnlinecommunicationAct", "computingunspecifiedAct",
                                     "skypeorvideocallAct", "OtherunspecifiedcomputingAct", "gamesAct",
                                     "computergamesAct", "gamblingAct", "unspecifedmassmediaAct",
                                     "readingAct", "TVAct", "RadioAct", "travelAct", "waitingAct", "unknownAct")


windows()

mypalette = rainbow(ncol(AggregatedActivities))
matplot(y = AggregatedActivities, type = 'l',xlab="Time", ylab = "Proportion of activites", main="(Monday) Individual data: Activities", lty = 1, pos=0, axes=FALSE, xlim=c(1,144), ylim=c(0,100), col = mypalette)

axis(1, at=1:144, labels=rownames(AggregatedActivities), by=10, pos=-1)
axis(2, at=c(0,100), labels=c("",""), pos=1)
axis(2, at=seq(0, 100, by=50),lwd.ticks=1, las=1, pos=1, cex=0.3)

rect(xleft=96,xright =73,ybottom=range(AggregatedActivities)[1],ytop=range(AggregatedActivities)[2], density=10, col = "blue")
```

However this graph is hardly readable, the legend is missing and the axis do not match. Could you help me please.

At the end of the day, I using David and Guillermo suggestions I created the following graphs:

a.) David solution please see the suggestion above

[image]

b.) Guillermo solution please see the suggestion above

[image]

The 2 graphs do not match, and I don't know why? Also how can i remove the month and year from David's plot?

Thanks

Comment: Regarding the month-year formatting, see [scales::date_format()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/date_format) and the `%R` format (or the `%H:%M` format).
Given that you have many legend items, try to aggregate them into groups or [highlight](https://github.com/yutannihilation/gghighlight) different important activities to reduce the information to show only important bits.

Comment: See also [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DavZim/6a5f694bcaa62e1465b55e2ad6d658fc) for the highlighting version

Comment: Please, do not change questions substantially. Now, the answers are useless for other SO users because the original question is gone. Please, revert your changes and post a new question instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tidy approach using the tidyverse would look like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

struct <- structure(c(0, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 17, 15, 
            14, 20, 25, 21, 157, 155, 155, 153, 150, 150, 147, 146, 145, 
            146, 146, 142, 134, 133, 124, 113, 113, 104, 85, 76, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 9, 6, 6, 13, 13, 5, 5, 5, 
            4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 4, 7, 5, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
            1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
            1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
            2, 4, 6, 6, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 
            3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 5), .Dim = c(20L, 52L), .Dimnames = list(
              c("04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", "04:50", "05:00", 
                "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", "06:00", "06:10", 
                "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", "07:10"), c("personalcareAct", 
                                                                         "sleepAct", "eatingAct", "workingAct", "studyAct", "tidyAct", 
                                                                         "foodprepAct", "dishesAct", "foodmanagementAct", "householdtidyAct", 
                                                                         "hobbyAct", "ironingAct", "laundryAct", "hobby2Act", "gardeningAct", 
                                                                         "petsAct", "diyAct", "hobby1Act", "vehiclemaintenanceAct", 
                                                                         "shoppingAct", "servicesAct", "tidyNotUsingInternetAct", 
                                                                         "InternetAct", "childcareAct", "adultcareAct", "organisationalworkAct", 
                                                                         "helpothersAct", "socialAct", "culturalAct", "libraryAct", 
                                                                         "sportseventsAct", "leisureAct", "sportsAct", "computerAct", 
                                                                         "unspecifiedartsAct", "correspondanceAct", "unspecifedhobbyAct", 
                                                                         "computingAct", "OnlinecommunicationAct", "computingunspecifiedAct", 
                                                                         "skypeorvideocallAct", "OtherunspecifiedcomputingAct", "gamesAct", 
                                                                         "computergamesAct", "gamblingAct", "unspecifedmassmediaAct", 
                                                                         "readingAct", "TVAct", "RadioAct", "travelAct", "waitingAct", 
                                                                         "unknownAct")))


df <- as_data_frame(struct) %>% 
  # add the time-of-day as a variable
  mutate(timeofday = rownames(struct)) %>% 
  # format the timeofday as a posix (date)
  mutate(timeofday = as.POSIXct(paste0("2000-01-01 ", timeofday, ":00")))

df_long <- df %>% 
  # gather the data into a long format
  gather("activity", "value", -timeofday) %>% 
  # group by timeofday and calculate the relative value
  group_by(timeofday) %>% 
  mutate(rel_value = value / sum(value))

# plot the values as an area-plot
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = timeofday, y = rel_value, fill = activity)) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you fro your solution - I have question could you explain please this code mutate(rel_value = value / sum(value)). Why are you taking rel_value? thanks

Comment: [mutate()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) creates a new variable or changes an existing variable. Using that function, we create the relative value (`rel_val`, as in relative value per group). That is, as we grouped by the time, we calculate the respective value relative to all the values of that time. In other words, we calculate the percentage... This allows us to then use the stacked area geometric of ggplot.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation, one more question I updated my  question, but the 2 solution do not match each other, sorry could you help me to understand why?..if you have time

Comment: As the code is not reproducible, I am not sure what the difference is. The idea of the code is very similar to mine though. One thing, the `reshape2::melt` coerces the activities to factors (see also `str(AggregatedActivities)`, and `str(melted_AggregatedActivities)`), this might change the order of the variables

Answer (score 0):

What about using `ggplot2` with the melted data frame:

```
library(ggplot2)
melted_AggregatedActivities <- melt(AggregatedActivities)
ggplot(melted_AggregatedActivities) + geom_col(aes(x = Var1,y = value,fill = Var2),position = "fill")  + theme(legend.position="none")
```

I get the following result:

[image]

I have removed the legend (`theme(legend.position="none")`) because it was too big.

Comment: thank you; one question please does value on y axis represent probabilities? Thanks

Comment: yes. The position = "fill" of ggplot normalizes all the y with a same x to 1, so you can think of it as a probability distribution given x. If you liked my response, please upvote it, thanks!